# How to create source code with dynamic FM creation

Tags: abap

I'm using FUNCTION_CREATE to create FM and everything is working fine, I'm passing bunch of parameters and FM is created like it should. But the problem is the Source Code part of FM. Is it possible to create it with FUNCTION_CREATE and which parameter should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create function modules with the source code, then you need to use **RS_FUNCTIONMODULE_INSERT** as it has a source parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I figured to check the other function groups and found that fm. Thx